# Lua Script Ends TCP Connection?

Tags: lua, wireshark, nmap

I've wrote the following script in Lua to be used with nmap:

```
action = function()
    local target = "46.121.76.117"

    local sock = nmap.new_socket("tcp")
    sock:set_timeout(10)

    local status, err = sock:connect(target, 17)

    if not status then
        -- Failed to connect
        stdnse.debug1("Couldn't connect to %s on port %d; %s",target, 17, err)
        sock:close()
        return
    end
```

The problem is that the script doesn't wait 1 second and prints immediately:

> Couldn't connect to 46.121.76.117 on port 17; TIMEOUT

Why is that?
I ran `nmap 46.121.76.117` and it shows port `17` as Open.

Comment: Can someone with enough points add `!`before the image so it can easier for other readers? :)

Comment: You set the timeout to 10 milliseconds?

Comment: @aschepler no 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `set_timeout` sets the timeout value in milliseconds, so if you want to set it to 10 seconds, you need to call `set_timeout(10*1000)`. This most likely explains the results you see with the client resetting the connection after 10ms.